# Change the values of a Ruby Hash

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, morris.js

I'm trying to make a donut chart using morris.js (http://www.oesmith.co.uk/morris.js/donuts.html) but am having some issues with getting the data to format correctly.

Currently this is how the data is formatted.

```
{"2D"=>"6768.96", "1DP"=>"293.63", "3D"=>"84.97", "1D"=>"361.83", "GR-RES"=>"19083.85", "GR-COM"=>"11254.69"}
```

Below is my current code

```
<%= content_tag :div, "", id: "shipments-by-service-type", data: {shipments: @details.group(:family).sum("base_charge + discount")} %>


jQuery ->
  Morris.Donut
    element: "shipments-by-service-type"
    data: $('#shipments-by-service-type').data('shipments')
```

This is my first experience passing data into js and parsing to make a graph any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How is the data actually showing up in the html when rendered on the client side in the `shipments-by-service-type` id?

Comment: `<div data-shipments="{"2D":"6768.96","1DP":"293.63","3D":"84.97","1D":"361.83","GR-RES":"19083.85","GR-COM":"11254.69"}" id="shipments-by-service-type">`

I want the the first element to be the label and the second to be the value.

Comment: One problem I see right away is that you either need to escape your quotes in `data-shipments` i.e. `\"` or change the outer double quotes to be single quotes

Comment: That is because when you do the JSON.parse in order to convert the text into an object, it will see the first double quote after the `=` and then it will see the next double quote after `{` and assume that it is done parsing and of course then you don't have a valid object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So once you correct the quote issue I pointed out in the comments above, either escape or switch the outer quote to be single quotes, this javascript will parse your input and get it ready for the donut graph

```
var dataArr = [];
var obj = $("#shipments-by-service-type-simple").data('shipments');
for ( var prop in obj) {
  dataArr.push({"label": prop, "value": obj[prop]});
}

Morris.Donut({
  element: 'donut-example',
  data: dataArr
});
```

Here is the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/axezax/1/edit).  It appears that raphael doesn't like the decimal values and is throwing errors.  Might want to round your values